# Apache HPLSQL - Permission Denied while running HPLSQL Query

Tags: hive, hive-hplsql

I'm trying to run a query using the hplsql command and getting this error. It seems to be a permission issue. My current logged in user is not being considered

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): Permission denied: user=anonymous, access=WRITE, inode="/user/anonymous/.staging":hdfs:hdfs:drwxrwxr-x
```

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the username in the `hplsql-site.xml` file.

The property that needs to be edited is

```
hplsql.conn.hive2conn
```

Here's how you can specify the property

```
<property>
  <name>hplsql.conn.hive2conn</name>
  <value>org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver;jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000;username;password</value>
  <description>HiveServer2 JDBC connection</description>
</property>
```

If you don't have a password for the username, you can skip the mentioning the password after the username